# Compute element overlap based on another column, pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

If I have a dataframe of the form:

```
 tag      element_id
  1          12
  1          13
  1          15
  2          12
  2          13
  2          19
  3          12
  3          15
  3          22
```

how can I compute the overlaps of the `tags` in terms of the `element_id` ?  The result I guess should be an overlap matrix of the form:

```
   1   2   3
1  X   2   2
2  2   X   1
3  2   1   X
```

where I put X on the diagonal since the overlap of a tag with itself is not relevant and where the numbers in the matrix represent the total `element_ids` that the two tags share.

**My attempts:**

You can try and use a for loop like :

```
for item in df.itertuples():
    element_lst += [item.element_id]
    element_tag = item.tag
# then intersect the element_list row by row. 
# This is extremely costly for large datasets
```

The second thing I was thinking about was to use `df.groupby('tag')` and try to somehow intersect on `element_id`, but it is not clear to me how I can do that with grouped data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `merge` + `crosstab`

```
# Find element overlap, remove same tag matches
res = df.merge(df, on='element_id').query('tag_x != tag_y')

pd.crosstab(res.tag_x, res.tag_y)
```

#### Output:

```
tag_y  1  2  3
tag_x         
1      0  2  2
2      2  0  1
3      2  1  0
```

Comment: Clean and elegant, damn I wish I knew these more advanced pandas commands. Thx :)

Comment: Yes, after the merge `pd.crosstab` is very concise to get the counts. It's also possible with `pivot_table` at that point (`crosstab` calls `pivot_table` after all :D), or a `groupby` + `size`.